# Email bouncing back with error code 550 5.7.708 Service unavailable

Tags: outlook-restapi

we have an application that is using the Outlook REST API v2 to allow the users to send emails from the app.

Today one of our clients send us a bug report, that after they created a new Office365 account for their company they can't send emails through our app. The current case was for sending email to hotmail.com account. The email bounces back with error code

> 550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted
>   from this IP.

The user also reports that they are able to send the same email from the Outlook web client.

I have found this issue on the network: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/608d046b-755a-4264-8cdd-fc34c72ccf8f/office-365-tenant-blacklisted-on-all-emails-sent-by-ms-outlook-2016?forum=onlineservicesexchange and am now wondering if this is just a bug on Outlook side or we have missed something on our end?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go here: https://sender.office.com/ and put the incriminate ip to delete it from the list.

Comment: The IP is of a user that is using our software and I don't have access to their account. The strange thing is that he was able to send messages from the web version of Outlook. That is why I asked if someone has more information about this issue.
But thank you for your answer!